# quck sort file handling in c

Tags: c, loops, file, sorting, struct

Hello guys I am new to c programming I got this code from a book and I trying to figure it out what does this code meant can anyone explain it? thanks

```c
    int partition (struct Data data[1000], int low, int high) {
      int pivot = data[high].G3;
      int i = (low - 1);

      for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++) {
        if (data[j].G3 > pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(&data[i], &data[j]);
        }
      }
      swap(&data[i + 1], &data[high]);
      return (i + 1);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the code is part of a quicksort routine.  This link might help explain what the function is intended to do: [Linear-time partitioning](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/quick-sort/a/linear-time-partitioning)

Comment: [THIS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) can be helpful

Comment: What does the book say next to the code?